# ZipEntry returns null When Calling for a Directory Inside an APK File

Tags: java, android, apk, zip, ipa

I'm trying to setup a function where apk files are placed in a specified directory, stored into an array[], then go through a for-each loop, creating a ZipFile instance then create a ZipEntry to call for the lib directory, and read the file names inside to help determine which apks are compatible for androids devices currently connected to PC. This is the code I have so far:

```
public File[] apkFileList;
private HashMap<String, File> apkInstallOptions = new HashMap<String, File>();

public void createAPKList() throws ZipException, IOException {
    apkFileList =  new File(".....(many dirs later)/APKDir/APKFiles").listFiles();
    System.out.println(apkFileList[apkFileList.length-1].getName());
    apkInstallOptions = storeAndSortFiles(apkFileList, apkInstallOptions);
}

private HashMap<String, File> storeAndSortFiles(File[] fileList, HashMap<String, File> storageList) throws ZipException, IOException{
    ZipFile apkDetails;
    for(File apk : fileList) {
        apkDetails = new ZipFile(apk);
        ZipEntry libFiles = apkDetails.getEntry("lib/");
        libFiles.isDirectory();
        InputStream inputStream = apkDetails.getInputStream(libFiles);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = null;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);

        }

    }
    return storageList;
}
```

When I run the code to test out if the mapping to the path looks good, I get the correct name for apk, but when I attempt to call for ZipEntry for the lib directory, it returns Null. I'm not sure what I'm forgetting and what I'm not considering to add in order to read the contents inside. I've seen solutions where the Zip/apk file was extracted and then read, but I only want to read the contents inside the lib directory. Is that possible?

Screenshot of what is seen inside the APK file that a lib file does exist (used 7-Zip to look inside):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directories do not exist in the zip format. They're artificially shown in desktop tools, but zip libraries only show the actual files that are present, and that excludes directories.

The files present in an APK would thus be for example:

```
lib/arm64-v8a/libhello.so
lib/armeabi-v7a/libhello.so
```

But there would be no entries for `lib` or `lib/armeabi-v7a`.

You can thus test if a ZipEntry is under the "lib" directory by calling:

```
zipEntry.getName().startsWith("lib/");
```

Comment: To be more accurate, directories in zip libraries are sometimes represented as empty files, but they don't add any value so they're often removed.

Comment: Is there a different class which other than zip classes which can store directories in zip or apk folders? At the moment, I'm considering considering creating a temp file to store extracted files, read through desired folders then remove the temp file, before continuing through the for loop.

Comment: Why do you need to store the directory entries? They wouldn't contain the information of which files are inside. Instead, just check if `zipEntry.getName().startsWith("lib/")` and you'll know if the file is in that directory or not.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I was clear in my last comment. What I want is to read the names of the directories within Lib directory and store the name in a list of string. The names found under lib don't need to be read from lib/. Would the AndroidManifest.xml contain that sort information?

Comment: The manifest does not contain that information, no. Even if you only need the directory names, I don't understand why you can't parse the zip entries as I suggested: if you find an entry called "lib/armeabi-v7a/libfoo.so", it means there is a director called 'armeabi-v7a' under lib, right?

Comment: I get what your suggesting. However, I seem to hit a different wall going this approach. Since for any APK file I store in my APKFiles Directory, I have no clear indicator of what .so files would be stored in `lib/<insert ABI version>/(the first or any existing .so file)` The first idea I could come up to resolve this is using regex to find any file that would be `"(.*).so"` or `"[d\\\\]*.so"` inside each ABI directory, but with my attempts keep getting null and research on topic seems to be little. (More focused on searching range of File names with regex.)

Comment: Sounds like a separate problem :)

Comment: Tried that, and get same NullPointerException. Created a separate thread regarding ZipFile/ZipEntry and Regex. Short answer is that it's not supported. Here is the answer regarding that if you're interested. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56411529/how-to-find-any-file-within-a-directory-of-a-zipfile/56411628#56411628)

Comment: What's not supported is fetching files that match the pattern, but you can go through all zip entries as suggested by the accepted solution. I hadn't realized that you were trying to call ZipFile.getEntry() with that pattern. You would obviously need to go through all entries and compare the name of the entry as I suggested. Sorry for not being more explicit.

Comment: No worries. I knew I could go through all the entries, but I considered that to be overkill to check all the entries and wanted to determine if there was a more precise approach before considering this route, if an apk somehow happen to be really large/bloated.